# How to use reduce without lambda

Tags: python, lambda

Beginners solution - works

Hi folks.  I succeeded in writing some code which returns true if all
items in a list are prime numbers.  I think this is a good candidate
for "reduce" - up to now I have only used reduce in conjunction with
lambda - is it possible to avoid lambda and use direct function

```
def is_prime(list):
    np = "Prime"
    for n in list:
        if n < 2:
            np = "NonPrime"
            print np
        else:
            for i in range(3, n):
                if n % i == 0:
                    np ="NonPrime"
                    print np
    return np
x = is_prime([3,5,13])
print x
```

alternatively using reduce

```
def is_prime_no(x):  #"True" represents Prime
    np = "True"
    if x < 2:
        np = "False"
    else:
        for i in range(3, x):   #int(math.sqrt(n))
            if x % i == 0:
                np ="False"
    return np
```

print is_prime_no(12)

```
def prime_check(a,b):
    if is_prime_no(a) == "True" and is_prime_no(b) == "True":
        return "True"
    else:
        return "False"

print "prime check result ", prime_check(13,17)
```

From here does not work

```
values = [13,17,2,19]
def list_prime_check(values):
    return reduce(prime_check, int(values))
print "Checking that all items in list are prime ", list_prime_check([0, 37, 40, 100])
```

Error message:

> int argument must be string or int not list

apologies for previous post - accidently sent without being completed

Comment: What do you expect `int(values)` to do?  As the error message says, you can't call `int()` on a list, and the items in `values` are already integers.

Comment: "code which returns true if _all_ items in a list are prime numbers" Why do you think that `reduce` would be a good choice for this, and not, well, [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#all)?

Answer (score 3):

Please use the Booleans `True` and `False` and not the strings `"True"` and `"False"`. The following is your function if you were to use Booleans rather than strings:

```
def prime_check(a,b):
    return is_prime_no(a) and is_prime_no(b)
```

But this would be incorrect as `a` is not a number but rather the previous result so it should be written as

```
def prime_check(a,b):
    return a and is_prime_no(b)
```

But I would suggest lifting the predicate and the reducer out and writing it as:

```
from operator import and_
def list_prime_check(values):
    return reduce(and_, map(is_prime_no, map(int, values)))
```

But that reduce is better written as:

```
    return all(map(is_prime_no, map(int, values)))
```

And then the maps could be removed:

```
    return all(is_prime_no(int(v)) for v in values)
```

Which is the form of this which I greatly prefer.